# acceptable design?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I am collecting information on products over time from different retailers. I would want to query the product's pricing over time from all the retailers as well as the retailer's price for the individual product over time, among other things. How would the design below stand up to the task?
(Postgres)

```
Product
-------
id = PK(int)
upc = VarChar(20, unique)
prices = FK(Price(int))
retailers = M2M(Retailer(int))

Retailer
--------
id = PK(int)
name = VarChar(124, unique)
products = M2M(Product(int))
prices = FK(Price(int))

Price
-----
id = PK(int)
timestamp = DateTime()
product = FK(Product(int))
retailer = FK(Retailer(int))
product_price = Decimal()
shipping_price = Decimal()
```

I am a little concerned with what seems like circular relationships, for example: do I need the prices relationship to also be present in the Retailer table? But it makes sense in terms of the queries I envision. Any suggestions? Also, how would you go about tracking whether it was in stock seeing as that varies depending on retailer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your product table should have one row per UPC (assuming that uniquely identifies a product).  It shouldn't reference prices or retailers.

Your retailer table should have one row per store.  It shouldn't reference products or prices.

```
Product
  product_id pk integer,
  upc varchar(20) unique

Retailer
  retailer_id pk integer,
  name varchar(128) unique
```

You can then have an intersection table that tells you which retailer sells which products

```
Retailer_Product
  retailer_id integer references retailer( retailer_id )
  product_id  integer references product( product_id )
  pk( retailer_id, product_id )
```

If you want to be able to track that a particular retailer used to sell a particular product but no longer does so, you could add dates to indicate when they started and stopped selling the product.  If you want to track that and allow the retailer to stop selling the product for a while and then start selling it again, you'd need to tweak the primary key.

Normally, for pricing, you'd store something like

```
Product_Pricing
  product_pricing_id integer pk,
  retailer_id integer references retailer(retailer_id),
  product_id  integer references product(product_id),
  price       integer, -- I'm following your example, I wouldn't store prices as integers
  from_ts     timestamp,
  to_ts       timestamp
```

This lets me indicate that a particular retailer offered a particular product for sale at a particular price for the period between the two timestamps.  If the product is sold at the same price for months at a time, I only need one row in the table for that.  If I want to change the price of the product on a minute-by-minute basis, I can do that as well.

If you are capturing prices rather than controlling price changes, it might make sense to write 1 row to the pricing table for every product for every retailer for every day (or whatever frequency you are polling for pricing on).  If you were building a price comparison site, you'll likely want a different data model than if you are building an Amazon site that allows different retailers to sell goods and manage their own pricing.  If you're intending to poll the actual source of truth once a day and want to have a row for every product for every retailer for every day, something like this would be reasonable.

```
Product_Pricing
  product_pricing_id integer pk,
  poll_dt     date,
  retailer_id integer references retailer(retailer_id),
  product_id  integer references product(product_id),
  price       integer, -- I'm following your example, I wouldn't store prices as integers
  in_stock    boolean
```

Depending on how frequently prices change or go out of stock, how many products and retailers you have, and how long you intend to retain this information, you might want to combine multiple otherwise identical rows

```
Product_Pricing
  product_pricing_id integer pk,
  first_poll_dt date,
  last_poll_dt  date,
  retailer_id integer references retailer(retailer_id),
  product_id  integer references product(product_id),
  price       integer, -- I'm following your example, I wouldn't store prices as integers
  in_stock    boolean,
```

Comment: sorry incorrectly labeled the products retailer relationship as FK instead of M2M. Using djangos ORM so I just forgot to add the associating table in my diagram

Comment: @Verbal_Kint - It's not obvious what the M2M in that model means from a data model perspective.  It might mean that you intend to create the Retailer_Product mapping table that I outlined in my answer so that the Product table wouldn't have a Retailer column and the Retailer table wouldn't have a Product column.  But if we're talking about data modeling, I would call that out explicitly as an additional table rather than making us guess what your ORM might be doing from a database design perspective.

Comment: The ORM does in fact create the mapping table you outlined in you answer. Also, with regards to your `from_ts` and `to_ts` suggestion, would an `available = Bool()` attribute accomplish the same thing if I added it to the `Product_Pricing` table? This is assuming capturing pricing information daily.

Comment: The above also assumes that I will be adding a new row regardless of price changes.

Comment: @Verbal_Kint - I'm not sure what an `available` column would tell you.  If you are capturing data once a day and you want one pricing row per product per retailer per day (the price could have changed mulitple times over the day so you don't know when the price was good for), then you'd have a single `poll_date` column that just has the date rather than two timestamps.

Comment: `available` would reference if the item was in stock when the price was collected for that retailer on that day (or period should the poll period be more frequent). I was referencing my edit in which I asked about the proper place to track that, I should have been more clear, sorry.

Comment: @Verbal_Kint - You could use `available` though `in_stock` might be more clear (`available` might refer to whether the retailer still sold the product rather than that they were merely out of stock).  But that would have nothing to do with the `from_ts` and `to_ts`/ `poll_date` columns that tell you when the data was good for.

Comment: So the `from_ts`, `to_ts` would be a way to prevent creating a new row if the price hasn't changed from the last poll date? If so, then I wouldn't be able to track `in_stock` in `Product_Pricing` seeing as it would possibly be overwritten on the next poll date if the price remains unchanged? Although, I guess I could just create a new row if either price or in_stock changes if that's the case...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43895/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-verbal-kint).